# Object.values returns a dictionary, what do you use to simply return a value?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am relatively new to Django, and I have been experimenting with the object model.  I have been having trouble pulling a single value from my database based on the user selecting a scenario name from a dropdown and then hitting a submit button.  This is what I am working with.

```
if request.method   =='POST' and 'submitdropdown1' in request.POST:
    entry = Scenario.objects.values().get(scenario_name=scenario_name)
    r  = entry.get('project_cost')
```

Values() returns a dictionary so:
  r = 'Decimal ("200")'

I would like for:
  r = 200

What should I use besides Values()?

Comment: Why is getting the value you want from the dictionary a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `values()` method returns a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) which retrieves dictionaries instead of model instances. When you use `.get` on those dictionaries, you are getting back the correct value from that field. In this case,  `entry['project_cost']` has the actual value `Decimal("200")`.

`Decimal` is a [module that's in the Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html). If you wish to get the integer value of an object of type `Decimal` you can quickly cast it to an integer like this:

```
r  = int(entry.get('project_cost'))
```

and then the `r` variable will equal the integer `200`.

Alternatively, if `project_cost` is an attribute of the `Scenario` model and you wish to work at the object level instead of with dicts, you could do something like this instead:

```
if request.method   =='POST' and 'submitdropdown1' in request.POST:
    entry = Scenario.objects.get(scenario_name=scenario_name)
    r  = int(entry.project_cost)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Very helpful explanation.